# BeautifulSoup: Get all elements that contain a certain attribute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a file that I want to make soup with- this is only an excerpt:

```
        <p facs="#facs_14_TextRegion_1624023825755_566">
       <lb facs="#facs_14_line_1624023773342_555" n="N001"/>Und wiewol eyn solcher Mensch behelt eyn <w>Frei<pc>-</pc>
       <lb/>heyt</w> seines willens, doch schwach und verletzet, daraus
       <lb facs="#facs_14_r1l25" n="N003"/>als eynem brunnen herfliessen alle ehrliche tugent und <w>tha<pc>-</pc>
       <lb/>ten</w> der heiden sampt iren wirckungen, So kan er doch vor
       <lb facs="#facs_14_r1l27" n="N005"/>der gnaden und ehe dann er wider zu recht gebracht ist,
       <lb facs="#facs_14_r1l28" n="N006"/>die gerechtigkeyt, die vor Gott gilt, nit erreychen, sonder
       <lb facs="#facs_14_r1l29" n="N007"/>ist vil mehr eyn knecht der Sünden, des Teüfels eygen
       <lb facs="#facs_14_r1l30" n="N008"/>und eyn feind Gottes und allen straffen diser welt <w>under<pc>-</pc>
       <lb/>worffen</w>, dann er wirdt beschwärt mit hunger, kummer,
       <lb facs="#facs_14_r1l32" n="N010"/>durst, frost, hitz, schmertzen, kranckheyt und wirdt entlich
       <lb facs="#facs_14_r1l33" n="N011"/>durch den tod zerstöret. Dann <q>die sünde ist durch eynen
       <lb facs="#facs_14_line_1623337148499_448" n="N012"/><note place="margin-right" facs="#facs_14_TextRegion_1624023908878_596">
       <lb facs="#facs_14_line_1623337734932_504" n="N001"/>Roma. 5.</note>menschen inn die welt kommen unnd durch die sünde der
       <lb facs="#facs_14_r1l35" n="N013"/>tod</q><note type="annotation"><ref type="biblical" cRef="Rm_5,12">Röm 5,12</ref>.</note>. Es seind aber die straffen diser ersten übertrettung
       <lb facs="#facs_14_r1l36" n="N014"/>denen, die von neuem durch die genad geboren werden,
       <lb facs="#facs_14_r1l37" n="N015"/>mit den sündern gemeyn, wiewol sie den neugebornen auch
       <lb facs="#facs_14_r1l38" n="N016"/>zur übung auffgelegt werden, Aber den ungerechten und
       <lb facs="#facs_14_r1l39" n="N017"/>Gottlosen werden sie zur straff zugeschickt.
    </p>
```

Now, what I want to do is get all  and their content, regardles of what the cRef's text actually is. (It's a standardised set of shorthands depicting bible passages). I think am not sure whether I can use `cRefs = soup.findAll(attrs={"type":"biblical"})`, as we might have elements that are type="biblical" but don't have a cRef.All elements that have a cRef should be, and I am not the one tagging the document, , though.

Any hints on how to do that?

Edit: my Code so far:

```
import bs4 as bs
with open('interim.xml', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(file, 'lxml')
Refs = soup.find_all(attrs={'type':'biblical'})
print(Refs)
```

expected output:

`[<ref cref="Gn_1,26-27" type="biblical">Gen 1,26f.</ref>, <ref cref="Sir_15,14" type="biblical">Sir 15,14</ref>, <ref cref="Rm_5,12" type="biblical">Röm 5,12</ref> ]`
(only an excerpt) - it might happen that not all of the elements share type="biblical", though.

for an individual element in Refs I can use `Refs[i].get('cref')` for retrieving the value, which I also need at a later time.

Is there a way in BS to tetrieve only elements that have a certain attribute?

Edit2: bcs I found out that I can do

```
Refs = soup.find_all(attrs={'cref':True})
```

All the best and thanks in advance,
K

Comment: Please provide some more details to clarify - [mcve] and also expected output. Would be great.

Answer (score 0):

After some more coffee, I searched again and found that

```
Refs = soup.find_all(attrs={'cref':True})
```

works flawlessly for what I want.

Comment: Great, an alternative would be to use `css selectors` to get the same result -> `soup.select('[cRef]')`